# Android Hide keyboard when changing fragments

Tags: android

When I change fragments. I am using this to close the keyboard because there is an EditText field on the screen. I just feel like there has to be a better way, but I havent found anything on detecting if the keyboard is on the screen.

```
Activity activity = getActivity();
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)  activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
try
{
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
}
catch (Exception e)
{

}
```

Comment: It's difficult to detect the keyboard, the API really only allows you to trigger the keyboard.

Answer (score 4):

In the activity where you implement the calling to various fragments, put the following...

```
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code in pause method:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    final InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    if (inputMethodManager != null && inputMethodManager.isActive()) {
        if (getCurrentFocus() != null) {
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The only real way I can think of is using the `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration config)` method:

Combination of [KeyboardHidden](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#keyboardHidden) and [Configuration](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html) should do it.

```
class MyFrag extends Fragment{

  @Override
  public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration config){
    //Check flags
    switch(config.keyboardHidden){
      case KEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO:
        // do something
        break;
      case KEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES:
        break;
    }
  }

}
```

This of course relies on you having the manifest and parent activity to accept these as config changes:

```
<activity ...
  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout"/>
```

Also you will note the `Activity` has the same overridable method, the activity will get the method first, then pass it on to the attached `Fragment`s.

For the observant you can do this on the fly using a context:

```
Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();
```

Hope that helps, it's meant to take into account hardKeyboards as well, but im sure you'll run into some device specific bug!